# Relation to model, within said model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord

so I'm working on a site where users are able to upload content that depends on other user uploaded content.

Is it possible to create these relations in a 'rails way?'

My setup would basically look something like (pseudo code)

```
Project
 field :name
 has_many :dependencies, class_name: 'Project'
end
```

Would something like this work? (probably not) Would using `:through` possibly work? Not sure how I should go about this.

I've tried googling this, to see if it's possible, but most of the results seem to be for multiple relations to the same class in a single model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from [RubyonRails.guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

You may want to store all employees in a single database model, but be able to trace relationships such as between manager and subordinates

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                      foreign_key: "manager_id"

  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

then, you can retrieve @employee.subordinates and @employee.manager.

Comment: I wasn't aware that this worked within the same class, thanks!